# Is there some way to add Stormcloud to startup application?

Tags: startup, startup-applications

I'm enjoing a lot Stormcloud, the downside is that it doesn't have a "startup" option so sometimes I forget to use it. Is there some way to add it to the startup applications?

Answer (score 1):

Open the unity dash and type `startup applications. There you can manage the applications that will start automatically with your session. Include Stormcloud there and it's done.

If you don't know the command, after you click `Add` inside `Startup Applications`, you'll see a `Browse` button. Click on the left side of Nautilus where it says `File System`. Click on the `bin` folder. Inside this `bin` folder you'll see all of the different applications installed. Scroll through until you find the right command.

Comment: I don't know the command :(

Comment: try just "stormcloud", without the quotes

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what Ubuntu desktop you are using, but ultimately, it'll always be a simple job.

If you are using the Unity desktop, then simply click the "power" icon in the top right hand corner of the screen and click "Startup Applications". You will see below the icon in question. You can find that little "power" icon in the top right hand corner of the Unity desktop.

[image: Icon needed]
[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

This dialogue box will appear. Simply click Add, choose the command to run on start-up (You can press Browse from there to save you time typing in the command, or if you know exactly what the command is, you can type it in) and then it should be saved to your startup applications preferences.

Comment: I don't know the command or where it is :(

Comment: For the command, try 'stormcloud' without the quotes. I could not directly find a link to confirm if this works.